# Adding a column for percent change to csv file using existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I am have a csv file with 2 columns (dates and stock prices) and I want to calculate the one percent change and add a new column. I want to do this because after this I want to group the data into positive % change and % percentage change.

```
datafile = "file.csv"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',na_values='null')
```

So far I tried these but they all failed

1.

```
x = df.pct_change()
df["1 day percent change"] = x
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

2.

```
df["1 day percent change"] = ((np.diff(df))/(df[:,1:]))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

3.

```
new_column = ((np.diff(df))/(df[:,1:]))
df = df.merge(new_column, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Can you help me identify the problem? Thank you!

Original df looks like this [image]

Comment: please provide printed text sample of your df

Comment: Also, please provide context of failures. Results are not expected? error?

Comment: Try specifying the target column: `df["1 day percent change"] = df['target_col'.pct_change()]`

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva i ran df["1 day percent change"] = df["1 day percent change".pct_change()] and got a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pct_change'

Comment: @Jerome just did - sorry didn't include initially

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo. I mean `df["1 day percent change"] = df['target_col'].pct_change()`, replacing 'target_col' by the name of the column you wanna calculate the percent change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misuse of pct_change in code block 1:

```
x = df.pct_change()
```

You use *pct_change* on the compete dataframe while it is a Series function.
Do that instead:

```py
x = df['close'].pct_change()
df["1 day percent change"] = x
```

Then code blocks 2 and 3, I am not sure what you want to achieve with:

```py
df[:,1:]
```

the correct syntax would be with iloc (df.iloc[:,1:]). But I am not sure what you want to achieve anyway, considering np.diff returns an array.
my understanding is that code block 1 does the trick you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The errors your seeing in your attempts 1, 2, and 3 are due to your data type being object (str) instead of a number (float).

use df.dtypes and more than likely your data types all show object for 'close' and 'adj close', etc.

```
df['close'] = df['close'].astype('float')
df["1 day percent change"] = df['close'].pct_change()
```